# Is it possible RAM not compatible with Macbook Pro?

Tags: upgrade, memory

As this is my first time dealing with HW of my Macbook Pro Early 2011 and need lot of money for service, I am quite nervous with this.

I want to upgrade my Macbook Pro RAM to 8GB. What I can find from Apple website is the current spec:

```
4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1333MHz DDR3 SDRAM; supports up to 8GB
```

I want to buy this RAM which is written for Mac Apple:

```
Corsair SO-DIMM DDR3 8GB PC10666 - CMSA8GX3M2A1333C9
```

Should I go straight away since the spec is equal? I just want to evade the possibility breaking my Macbook Pro.

Comment: There is no 'early 2011 Mac Pro'. You mean Macbook Pro? Usually the auto-find-my-RAM apps from Crucial, Corsair, Kingston etc are reliable. If you didn't use the app, then make sure you triple-check your data. ie, don't confuse a Mac Pro with a Macbook Pro

Comment: Sorry I have clarified my question. I usually abbreviates Macbook to Mac..

Comment: Do you have the auto find RAM app for Corsair URL? I seem can't find it. Other brands are not sold here..

Comment: @Rendy [SystemScanner Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner)

Comment: I wasn't looking for Crucial since it isn't sold here. I have upgraded to Corsair anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAM you listed there **will work perfectly fine**.
Whenever buying RAM just make sure you have the **correct type** (*DDR3 in your case*) and the **correct speed** (*1333 MHz or PC10666 in your case*).

It won't 'break' your MacBook but instead it just **won't boot if you have the incorrect type or speed** of RAM in your MacBook. RAM has no saved state when turning your computer off so logically it couldn't harm your MacBook if you switch it out for incorrect RAM and then put the correct one back in.

So summarized: The RAM you listed **will work** but in the future always **check for speed & type** (I like to use MacTracker for this).

Comment: Thanks! Based on your answer, I was confident to buy it and have upgraded my RAM successfully.

Comment: @Rendy no problem, glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that bad RAM will "break" your MacBook. However, it may not boot with bad RAM installed, but putting the original RAM back in should allow it to function properly again.

Really, as long as the RAM is made for Mac, has the right form-factor and specs, and is returnable, I'd give it a try.